# Nuxt.js button that performs fetch() and outputs to a variable in the template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to output the results of a fetch request into my template/page when a button is clicked on. Here is my code

I have the following method that pulls json from another server:

```
methods: {
    talktoServer: function () {
          this.ip = fetch('http://localhost:10000/', {
            method: 'GET',
          })
.then((res) => res.json())
        }
}
```

The following in my template with a button that executes this method and displays it:

```
<button @click="talktoServer">click</button>
      <li v-for="a of ip" v-bind:key="a">{{ a.data }}</li>
```

And lastly data in my export default to store the results:

```
  data() {
    return {
      ip: [],
    }
  }
```

The issue I am having is when this function is outside of the "methods" area of the script it works perfectly (I assume it's because it is not waiting for a button to be clicked and loads based on fetch() order).

I have tested the button is working with an alert(this.ip). I get the promise object but at least I know it's grabbing it. Can also see it in the network traffic when clicking the link (the full request I'm expecting).

**My question is:** How do I place the output of the results of my function (talktoServer) into the template variable {{ a.data }} AFTER the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either make the function `async` to `await` the result of `fetch`:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
  async talkToServer () {
      this.ip = await fetch(...).then(res => res.json())
                  
      // Or
      const res = await fetch(...)
      this.ip = await res.json()
    }
  }
}
```

Or assign `this.ip` in the `.then` callback of `fetch`:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    talkToServer: function () {
      fetch(...)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.ip = data) 
    }
  }
}
```